# Find Matrix A given two eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A be a matrix such that $$ u = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$$ is a 2-eigenvector and $$v=\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}$$ is a 3-eigenvector.

Find $$(A^2+4A+I)w$$ where w=u−v

I have absolutely no idea where to start!! Thank you guys

Comment: What does 2-eigenvector mean?

Comment: I assume it means $u$ has eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: Hint, first note that by if $M = A^2 + 4A + I$ you have $M(u-v) = Mu - Mv$ so you only need to compute $Mu, Mv$.  Then $Mu = (A^2 + 4A + I)u = \ldots$ (use the fact that $Au = 2u$ repeatedly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

It is not $A$  which is asked for, but 
$$(A^2-4A+I)(u-v)=\bigl(A^2-4A+I\bigr)u-\bigl(A^2-4A+I\bigr)v .$$
Now, by definition, $Au=2u$ and $Av=3v$. Can you proceed?